# Css Floating without moving other floats

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to float 5 pictures next to eachother; Upon hover of any of them i want the hovered over image to grow in width without pushing the images next to it Away from it. I want everything to stay in place but for the picture being hovered over to grow in size. How would i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/C0GECjNF)***

Hi now used to this css without floating

**Css**

```
.parent{
border:solid 1px red;
  width:100px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}
.parent img{
border:solid 1px black;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8193632933d351ea68ec1eae12f82057?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8193632933d351ea68ec1eae12f82057?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8193632933d351ea68ec1eae12f82057?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8193632933d351ea68ec1eae12f82057?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
      <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8193632933d351ea68ec1eae12f82057?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/C0GECjNF)***

### ---------------

---

***[Updated demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Sj7IpB2v)***

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/syFBFxem
This is my problem right here thank you for your help :) When you hover over a photo you will notice that things move in a unexpected way